# При сравнении данных из файла и пользовательского ввода происходит ошибка

Tags: python

Программа - викторина с 4 вариантами ответа . Для проведения игры нужно данные из текстового файла переместить по переменным . Данные представлены в файле в таком виде :

```
ТЕМА ВИКТОРИНЫ 
1 БЛОК ДАННЫХ
2 БЛОК ДАННЫХ 
...
```

Каждый блок - это

```
ТЕМА ВОПРОСА
ВОПРОС
1 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА
2 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА
3 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА 
4 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА 
ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ 
КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ВОПРОСУ
```

Вот моя программа :

```py
import sys

def open_file (way,mode,coding) :  
    """
    Проверяет наличие файла на нужном месте и открывает его
    """ 
    try : 
        f = open(way,mode,encoding=coding)
    except IOError as e : 
        print ("Невозможно открыть файл !\n")
        print ("Произошла ошибка : \n\t"+e)
        input ("Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти ...")
        sys.exit()
    else : 
        return f 

def welcome (f) : 
    """
    Приветствуем пользователя
    """
    print ("\t\tДобро пожаловать в игру \"Викторина\"\n")
    print (f.readline())

def data (f) : 
    """
    Распределяет данные по переменным
    """
    heading = f.readline() # заголовок
    question = f.readline() # вопрос
    answers = []  # список ответов
    for i in " "*4:
        answers.append(f.readline())
    true = f.readline() # правильный ответ
    comment = f.readline() # комментарий
    return heading , question , answers , true , comment

def game (f) :
    """
    Проводит игру и возвращает количество баллов
    """
    pools = 0

    # присваиваем данные переменным
    heading , question , answers , true , comment = data(f)
    while heading != "" :

        print (heading,"\n")
        print (question,"\n")

        number = 0
        for answer in answers  : 
            number += 1
            print(number, "-", answer)

        # принимаем ответ 
        user_answer = input ("Введите правильный ответ : ")

        # проверяем 
        if user_answer == true :
            pools += 1
            print ("Правильно !")
        else :
            print ("Неправильно !")
            print (user_answer == true , type(user_answer),user_answer,type(true),true) # узнаём тип данных и значение переменных
            print ("Правильный ответ -",true)

        print (comment) 
        # присваиваем данные переменным для следующего цикла
        heading , question , answers , true , comment = data(f)

    f.close()
    return pools

def end (pools) : 
    """
    Заканчивает игру
    """
    print ("\nВикторина окончена !")
    print ("\nВы набрали",pools,"баллов .")

def main () :
    """
    Запускает игру
    """
    f = open_file("quiz.txt","r","utf-8")
    welcome (f)
    pools = game(f)
    end(pools)

main()
input ("Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти ...")
```

Вот файл из которого я беру данные , в нём один блок

```
Столовая из 2008
Вкусный борщ , с капусткой , но не красный 
Что добавляется в борщ ? 
сосисочки
вкусный чай
непонятный салат
капуста 
4
Но чай - это сила !
```

Я запускаю программу , и вот что у меня получается :

```
                Добро пожаловать в игру "Викторина"

Столовая из 2008

Вкусный борщ , с капусткой , но не красный


1 - сосисочки

2 - вкусный чай

3 - непонятный салат

4 - капуста

Введите правильный ответ : 4
Неправильно !
4
 <class 'str'> 4 <class 'str'> False
Правильный ответ - 4

Но чай - это сила !
Викторина окончена !
Вы набрали 0 баллов
Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти ...
```

Почему - то значения переменных одинаковы , тип тоже , но они не равны . Что это такое и как исправить ? Как я понимаю проблема связана с кодировкой , но я новичок и сам разобраться не могу .

Comment: readline() - Считывает из файла одну строку и возвращает её. При считывании символ новой строки \n присутствует в конце каждой из строк. Его может не быть лишь в последней строке

Comment: Как это исправить ? \n в строке нет , тогда как его убрать ?